# Local storage of Web BrowserAPI not working

Tags: javascript

I have used local storage to store user's password in my webpage for authentication. However, on hosting the website, the local storage has stopped working at all. How can I fix this?

```js
localStorage.setItem('password', {{userInput }})
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you done any debugging? What is actually happening?

Comment: What you posted has syntax errors. If it is a server template, you need quotes and an end bracket `localStorage.setItem('password', "{{userInput }}")`

Comment: localstorage only allow you to store strings so ensure to `stringify` your data to store

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers block localStorage for Non-HTTPS sites. Check your browser's console for problem/warnings like: "localStorage blocked - not secure context".

And i thinkk there is a bug in your code. Try this:

```
localStorage.setItem('password', document.GetElementByID('password-input').value;)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 localStorage.setItem('password', JSON.stringify(userInput))
```